# "Todo el mundo" as "everyone"

Tags: modismos

I want to ask a question about the use of "todo el mundo".

I was reading this sentence below:

> No penséis que a todo el mundo en España le gustan los toros.

I roughly translated this first as:

> Don't think that the whole world in Spain likes the bulls.

but then that didn't make sense.

I thought it would be translated as

> Don't think that everyone in Spain likes the bulls.

This made more sense, but I struggle to make the link between "todo el mundo" and "everyone" since *mundo* is spanish for *world* and *everyone* implies a specific population set.

How is *todo el mundo* linked to the idea of *everyone* in Spanish?

Comment: by the way, you mean bullfighting not the bulls

Comment: "Todo el mundo" is a set phrase in Spanish meaning "everyone". Native speakers do not analyse it literally word by word, but as a unit in and of itself. This same phrasing can be seen in French (*tout le monde*) and Portuguese (*todo mundo*).

But, that said, "all the world" isn't so different semantically from "every one / every body".

Answer (score 5):

"Todo el mundo" doesn't necessarily mean "literally every single person in the world". It's just an idiomatic way to say "everybody".

Some alternatives to "todo el mundo" are "toda la gente", "todas las personas" and "todos":

> No penséis que a toda la gente en España le gustan los toros.
>
> No penséis que a todas las personas en España les gustan los toros.
>
> No penséis que a todos en España les gustan los toros.

If you want something closer to the English words "everyone" and "everybody", you can also say "toda persona" (it's not the most natural way to say it, though):

> No penséis que a toda persona en España le gustan los toros.

Comment: everyone in English is not close to toda persona. Toda person is every person.

Comment: @Lambie It's the closest thing that doesn't sound wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You could also get away with saying

### Cada Uno

The transaltion being: `each one`... or even `every one`

> No penseís que a cada uno en España le gustan los toros.

"Todo el mundo" probably has its roots and etymological reasonings hidden somewhere in an archaic linguistic library, but I'm not up to researching all of that.  To me, it sounds a bit hyperbolic.  It even almost sounds like the world is *inside* Spain, in the context of your sentence.  But, hey, Spanish isn't my first language anyway, so I digress.

*A cada uno lo suyo.*

Comment: "Uno" would be a pronoun there, but it's antecedent is unclear there. You'd need to say "De todas las personas que hay en España, no penséis que a cada una le gustan los toros". Even then, "cada" implies some sort of distributive relationship (as in your example, "A cada uno lo suyo").

Comment: I meant "its antecedent", of course. And I'd have removed one of the "there"s, had I reread the comment before saving.